# case statement and comparison operator

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, comparison-operators

Having trouble with a case statement where the length of a string is evaluated. More in particular the part that isn´t working corresponds with the line containing [[ ${#numPase} -lt 8 ]]).

```
  read numPase
  case $numPase in
     q|Q) var_cntrl_pase_ok=false
          ;;
     (*[!0-9]*|'')
          echo " "
          echo "Variable must contain integers. Press key to continue."
          read
          ;;
     [[ ${#numPase} -lt 8 ]])
          echo " "
          echo "Variable must have 8 digits. Press key to continue."
          read
          ;;
  esac
```

NOTE:
Variable numPase takes value from user input.
First case determines if user has pressed q or Q to quit menu loop. Second and third cases are self-explanatory

Why isn´t the 8 digit validation working?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern *must* be one or more globs separated by vbars. Any text in the pattern will be treated as a glob and *never* as a command.